# Rotating contents of an SVG text element

Tags: javascript, svg, rotation

I 'm working on rotating the text in an SVG text element. Whene a rotation is performed using `transform:rotate(angle,x,y)` entire text element is rotated. This creates an issue that positioning of the text element will be modified.

I understand this behavior, because rotaion causes tanslation of co-ordinates. But what I want to do is, the 'x' and 'y' position should always be the bottom of text element.

For example, the following code will create a text element at 50, 50

```
<text x='50' y='50'>My Text </text>
```

Now, (left, bottom) of text is (50, 50). If I rotate it by 90, then (left, top) will be 50, 50.

So, for all kind of rotations, I don't want to change the position of text element. How can I do this?

Comment: I tried transform-origin but its not working as expected. I have no idea how this property works. I'm giving 'center' as value to this but still it's not rotating from center

Answer (score 1):

```
EDIT
```

Sorry for my original answer below...I had not yet had my first cup of coffee;)

Try adding text-anchor="end" and dy="1"

```
IGNORE BELOW
```

Try the following:

Text rotate attribute is an object that specifies or receives a list of individual character rotation values. The last rotation value rotates all following characters.

```
myText.setAttribute("rotate","deg1, deg2, deg3, deg4, ...")

 rotationNumbs=myText.getAttribute("rotate")
```

~ or ~
 [ NumberList = ] myText.rotate [ = NumberList ]

Answer (score 1):

You can anchor the text in different positions using `text-anchor`. For example, if you rotate the text like this:

```
<text id="mytext" x='50' y='50'>My Text 
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform" begin="0s" dur="5s" type="rotate" 
                    from="0 50 50" to="360 50 50" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</text>
```

It will use the upper-left corner as an anchor-point. You can move it to the center using:

```
<text id="mytext" x='50' y='50' text-anchor="middle">My Text 
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform" begin="0s" dur="5s" type="rotate" 
                    from="0 50 50" to="360 50 50" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</text>
```

And now it will rotate anchored in the center: see this **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/DMPB2/)**.

You might also want to experiment with other anchor and baseline properties, if this is not exactly what you want. See: [SVG Spec - 10 Text - 10.9 Alignment properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#AlignmentProperties)

Comment: I tried it, but what I am looking for is rotating should not rotate the entire box only the text inside box. For example if text before rotation is at (x1,y) and (x2,y) then after rotation it should be at (x1, y) and (x2, y+height of text) irrespective of rotation angle. Is it only possible to achieve using mathematical calculation for rotation on case by case basis?

Comment: The example above only rotates the text, not the box (try the JSFiddle I posted). To obtain height of text you will need to calculate the bounding box since it depends on font-metrics. It's not clear what you exect. Could you provide an example of what you want (ex: a drawing, an image indicating those coordinates before and after would be useful)